# Macro Excel - Search Range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vba

Would be grateful if anyone can help me out with the following. I have a sequence of cells in one row and want to match each cell to the appropriate column (has same header) in the same row. All data is on the same sheet.

For ease of reference I have data in the following format

```
ACT001 | ACT002 | ACT003 | ADV001 | ADV002 | ADV003 | G      | H      | I 
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
       |        |        |        |        |        | ACT001 |        | 
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
       |        |        |        |        |        | ACT001 | ADV001 |
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
       |        |        |        |        |        | ACT003 | ADV002 | ADV003
```

And i want to achieve the following with a macro :

```
ACT001 | ACT002 | ACT003 | ADV001 | ADV002 | ADV003 | G      | H      | I 
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
ACT001 |        |        |        |        |        | ACT001 |        | 
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
ACT001 |        |        | ADV001 |        |        | ACT001 | ADV001 |
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
       |        |ACT003  |        | ADV002 | ADV003 | ACT003 | ADV002 | ADV003
```

As you can see I would like to match the cells from columns G-I to the appropriate column and in the same row.
The above is just a small extract. The actual table is bigger.

I can do the above with a series of IF statements and FIND formulas but was hoping for a quicker way with a macro. Grateful for any help.
Thanks

Comment: I wrote an answer for doing this with an easy formula. If you still want to do it with VBA you will have to get started on your own. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much quicker with a formula than a VBA script. Even the formula is not very complicated.

Assuming this is your sheet

```
  |   A    |   B    |   C    |   D    |   E    |   F    |   G    |   H    |   I   
  | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
1 | ACT001 | ACT002 | ACT003 | ADV001 | ADV002 | ADV003 | G      | H      | I 
2 |        |        |        |        |        |        | ACT001 |        | 
3 |        |        |        |        |        |        | ACT001 | ADV001 |
4 |        |        |        |        |        |        | ACT003 | ADV002 | ADV003
```

#### 1. Solution with an `IF` statement

Write the following formula into cell `A2`:

```
=IF($G:$G=A$1,$G:$G,IF($H:$H=A$1,$H:$H,IF($I:$I=A$1,$I:$I,"-")))
```

And then copy it to `A2:F4`

---

#### 2. Solution with `HLOOKUP`

Write the following formula into cell `A2`:

```
=IFNA(HLOOKUP(A$1,$G2:$I2,1,FALSE ),"-")
```

And then copy it to `A2:F4`

---

The second solution should be the same length no matter how many columns you have. The first one gets longer with every additional column.

Please notice: The correct use of the `$` in these formulas fixing some of the rows/columns made it possible to copy one formula into the whole range.

Comment: Added a second (even shorter) solution with `HLOOKUP`.